# Creating a color palette in R for a pie chart with 19 categorical variables

Tags: r, pie-chart, color-palette

**Heads up**: This post is a bit lengthy. Apologies.

I'm running an analysis of my book reading habits. I'm starting with the simple question "what genre do I read the most". I answered this question using the aggregate function. Now I'm trying to make a pie chart. I've successfully created a pie chart. The below data.frame was created. The "label" column was created so that the labels in the pie chart had both the genre and the percentage.

| genre | number_read | label |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Fairytales | 93 | Fairytales, 21.5% |
| General Fiction | 7 | General Fiction, 1.6% |
| Mystery | 29 | Mystery, 6.7% |
| Romance | 117 | Romance, 27.1% |
| Short Story | 2 | Short Story, 0.5% |
| Weird | 4 | Weird, 0.9% |
| Classics | 28 | Classics, 6.5% |
| Fanfiction | 25 | Fanfiction, 5.8% |
| Historical Fiction | 12 | Historical Fiction, 2.8% |
| Nonfiction | 20 | Nonfiction, 4.6% |
| Satire | 1 | Satire, 0.2% |
| Thriller | 6 | Thriller, 1.4% |
| Young Adult | 2 | Young Adult, 0.5% |
| Environmental Fiction | 1 | Environmental Fiction, 0.2% |
| Fantasy | 36 | Fantasy, 8.3% |
| Horror | 28 | Horror, 6.5% |
| Paranormal | 3 | Paranormal, 0.7% |
| Science Fiction | 16 | Science Fiction, 3.7% |
| Unknown | 2 | Unknown, 0.5% |

The problem is that I have too many variables for the default color scheme. I need to create my own. I know there are countless questions regarding color palettes on Stack Overflow. I've tried them, and I can't get them to work. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Here's what the chart looks like with the default color scheme:

[image: pie chart with too many variables]

**Side question** Does anyone know how to get rid of the tiny greyed out numbers around(300, 400, 0, etc)?

Here's the code I used to get it:

```
require(ggplot2)
require(ggrepel)# allows pie chart labels to be outside chart
require(tidyverse)
require(dplyr)
library(ggmap)
library(RColorBrewer)

#positions of the labels:
genre.label.pos <- genre.count %>% 
mutate(csum = rev(cumsum(rev(number_read))), 
     pos = number_read/2 + lead(csum, 1),
     pos = if_else(is.na(pos), number_read/2, pos))

ggplot(data=genre.count, aes(x=1, y=number_read, fill=genre))+
geom_col(width=1, color=1)+
coord_polar(theta="y")+
geom_label_repel(data = genre.label.pos,
               aes(y = pos, label = paste0(genre.count$label)),
               size = 4.5, nudge_x = 1, show.legend = FALSE) +
guides(fill = guide_legend(title = "Genre"))+
theme(axis.text.y = element_blank(), #gets rid of values on y-axis
    axis.ticks.y= element_blank(), #gets rid of tick marks on y-axis
    axis.title = element_blank(),  #gets rid of title
    legend.position = "none", # Removes the legend
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"))
```

I tried creating my own color palette. Hex values used are from color brewer

```
genre_palette <- (c("#fb9a99","#1b9e77","#e6ab02",
                "#e7298a","#d95f02","#66a61e",
                "#1b9e77","#e41a1c","#377eb8",
                "#bd0026","#dd1c77","#66c2a5","#d4b9da",
                "#006d2c","#238443","#525252",
                "#4d004b","#225ea8","#8c510a"))
```

I tried various ways of getting this palette to display in my chart.

Method A:

```
#original_ggplot_code_above()+
scale_fill_manual(values = "genre_palette")
```

Method B:

```
#original_ggplot_code_above()+
scale_fill_manual(values = "#fb9a99","#1b9e77","#e6ab02",
                "#e7298a","#d95f02","#66a61e",
                "#1b9e77","#e41a1c","#377eb8",
                "#bd0026","#dd1c77","#66c2a5","#d4b9da",
                "#006d2c","#238443","#525252",
                "#4d004b","#225ea8","#8c510a")
```

Method C: Switch scale_manual for scale_fill_brewer and try both methods A and B again

```
#method A
#original_ggplot_code_above()+
scale_fill_brewer(values =genre_palette)

#method B
#original_ggplot_code_above()+
scale_fill_brewer(values = "#fb9a99","#1b9e77","#e6ab02",
                "#e7298a","#d95f02","#66a61e",
                "#1b9e77","#e41a1c","#377eb8",
                "#bd0026","#dd1c77","#66c2a5","#d4b9da",
                "#006d2c","#238443","#525252",
                "#4d004b","#225ea8","#8c510a")
```

Method D: Switch hex color codes for base r colors and try methods A/B again

```
#method A:
genre_palette <- c("red","coral","darkred","chocolate1","cornsilk4","cyan1",
               "darkgoldenrod2","darkorchid2","deeppink2","darkslategray4","chartreuse4",
               "brown1","blueviolet","aquamarine","blue3","azure4","darkorange3",
               "brown3","burlywood4")
#original_ggplot_code_above()+
scale_fill_manual(values = genre_palette)

#method B
#original_ggplot_code_above()+
scale_fill_manual(values = "red","coral","darkred","chocolate1","cornsilk4","cyan1",
               "darkgoldenrod2","darkorchid2","deeppink2","darkslategray4","chartreuse4",
               "brown1","blueviolet","aquamarine","blue3","azure4","darkorange3",
               "brown3","burlywood4")
```

Error message for method A:

```
Insufficient values in manual scale. 19 needed but only 1 provided.
```

Error message for method B:

```
Error in discrete_scale(aesthetic, "manual", pal, breaks = breaks, limits = limits,  : 
unused arguments ("#bd0026", "#dd1c77", "#66c2a5",
"#d4b9da","#006d2c","#238443","#525252","#4d004b","#225ea8", "#8c510a")
```

Error message for method C:

```
Error in discrete_scale(aesthetics, "brewer", brewer_pal(type, palette,  :
unused arguments (values = "#fb9a99", "#d4b9da", "#006d2c", "#238443", "#525252", "#4d004b",
"#225ea8", "#8c510a")
```

Error message for method D:

```
-Method B: same as method B

-Method A: see below:
```

When I rerun the ggplot code, here's the color scale that shows up:
[image]

Colors are in the wrong place and there are still variables without their own slices. Any suggestions? What am I doing wrong? I don't need those specific colors- I just need 19 colors- any colors.

Comment: Please share your data using `dput`?

Comment: Your frequency table or a barplot are preferable to the evil pie chat.

Answer (score 1):

I am facing the same more than 20 colors pie chart and tried your method. Actually, you can twig your program to

```r
scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "coral", "darkred", 
                             "chocolate1", "cornsilk4", "cyan1",
                             "darkgoldenrod2", "darkorchid2", "deeppink2",
                             "darkslategray4", "chartreuse4", "brown1",
                             "blueviolet", "aquamarine", "blue3", 
                             "azure4", "darkorange3", "brown3", 
                             "burlywood4"))
```